# How to rewrite less code when using MLModels in Xcode

Tags: swift, oop, coreml, createml

**Abstract**: When I drag in an `.mlModel` into `Xcode`, `Xcode` generates a class interface for the model.

- All the model Inputs I use accept *common* initializer arguments,
- return *unique* Input classes, which are passed to the model's `predict(input:UniqueInput)` method and
- those return a *unique* `ModelOutput` instance
- which has a *common* `lazy var dependent: String` property.

**Problem**: The unique classes generated every time I drag in a new `.mlModel` requires me to rewrite code every time.

**Goal:** to take advantage of the common arguments and dependent property in order to minimize as much as possible the amount of code I need to rewrite when I drag in new `.mlModels`.

**Current Failing Attempt**
I tried to have the autogenerated model input conform to a `ModelVersion1` protocol so that newly generated model inputs would have a Type in common.  However protocols with initializers  require that the initializer implementation has the `required` keyword for classes which I don't have control over in autoGenerated classes.

```
func createRunningDataFrame() {
    var transactions: [Transaction] = []
    let model = try? MITO_1(configuration: MLModelConfiguration())
    URLRequest.streamFor(ticker: "MITO") { (runningFrame: DataFrame, price, ticker) in

      // ----------------------------> key line ----------------------
        guard let dependent: Double = try? model?.prediction(input: runningFrame.modelInput()!).dependent.double,
      // <-------------------------------------------------------------

        let direction = Direction(dependent: dependent) else { return }
        URLRequest.transact(direction, price, ticker) { transaction in
            transactions.append(transaction)
        }
    }
}
```

**Used Code**

(Auto generated)

```
class MITO_1 {
    func prediction(input: MITO_1Input) throws -> MITO_1Output {
        return try self.prediction(input: input, options: MLPredictionOptions())
    }
}


class MITO_1Input { 
    init(daysOfWeek: String, tradingsHours: String, quarters: String) {
        self.daysOfWeek = daysOfWeek
        self.tradingsHours = tradingsHours
        self.quarters = quarters
    }
}

class MITO_1Output : MLFeatureProvider {
    lazy var dependent: String = { [unowned self] in 
        return self.provider.featureValue(for: "dependent")!.stringValue
    }()
}
```

DataFrame

```
extension DataFrame {
    
    func modelInput<T: ModelVersion1>() -> T? {
        guard let daysOfWeek = self.cell(for: "daysOfWeek"),
        let tradingsHours = self.cell(for: "tradingsHours"),
        let quarters = self.cell(for: "quarters") else { return nil }
        return T(
            daysOfWeek: daysOfWeek,
            tradingsHours: tradingsHours,
            quarters: quarters
        )
    }    
}
```

Conformance
`ERROR: Initializer requirement 'init(daysOfWeek:tradingsHours:quarters:)' can only be satisfied by a 'required' initializer in non-final class 'MITO_1Input'`

```
extension MITO_1Input: ModelVersion1 {}

protocol ModelVersion1: AnyObject {
    init(daysOfWeek: String, tradingsHours: String, quarters: String)
}
```

String

```
extension String { 
    var double: Double? {
        Double(self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy the auto-generated class to your own Swift file. Disable the auto-generation. Modify the Swift file to suit your needs.

Note that the auto-generated file is there just for convenience. It wraps the `MLModel` API. You can use this API directly, so you don't *have* to use the auto-generated stuff.

Comment: How can I disable the autogeneration?

Comment: In the settings for the app, just search for "CoreML Compiler" and it lets you choose between Swift, Objective-C, or not generating any code.

Comment: I'm not finding it in the Project's build settings, I'm not finding it in the App's target build settings either.

Comment: Make sure "All" settings are selected (not just "Basic").

Comment: yay. in my projects build settings -all I found it.  Thank you!